# DDD aggregate roots and entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have an `Invoice` object which has an `InvoiceType`. Now, by looking at this situation, `InvoiceType` can exist without invoice. Should i treat `Invoice` as one aggregate root, and `InvoiceType` as another aggregate root within it's aggregate, and connect those to via ID reference, or InvoiceType should just be an entity within Invoice aggregate?

Also, when creating invoice, user must be able to choose Invoice Type from dropdown, which suggests me that it should have it's own repository.

Am I right to treat `InvoiceType` as separate aggregate?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what an InvoiceType is? Can two InvoiceTypes be different if they have the exact same properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right to treat `InvoiceType` as separate aggregate?

If `InvoiceType` is an entity, and if two different `Invoices` can have "the same" invoice type, then yes - you need to treat `InvoiceType` as a separate aggregate, with its own repository, and connect them via ID reference.